# How to create a list of dictionaries in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Intuitively, one would try something like:

```
interface Port_Mapping {
  number: Port_role
}
port_mappings: Port_Mapping[{number: Port_role}] = [];
```

where `Port_role` is an interface and number is an integer key. However this is met with:

> Type '{ number: Port_role; }' cannot be used as an index type.

Then one might try to change to:

```
interface Port_Mapping {
  number: Port_role
}

port_mappings: Port_Mapping[] = [];

this.port_mappings.push({5: Port_role.input})
```

However this doesn't work either because number in the interface is actually a name not a type and you end up with:

> Argument of type '{ 5: Port_role; }' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type 'Port_Mapping'.   Object literal may only specify known
>   properties, and '5' does not exist in type 'Port_Mapping'.

In my case, I want a list of dictionaries where each dictionary is of the form:

`[{key1: value1, key2: value2, key3: value3}]`

Comment: What is `Port_role`?

Comment: @VLAZ

export enum Port_role {
  input = "INPUT",
  output = "OUTPUT",
  unassigned = "UNASSIGNED"
}

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Angular. Please do not specify it as a tag just because you're currently working in an Angular project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
interface Port_Mapping {
  [index: number]: Port_role
}
```

The [index: number] is an indexer - can be used only in interfaces, and means you can index the object instance using it.

Your first try doesn't make much sense in TS, you are declaring a variable `port_mappings` to be of type `Port_Mapping` indexed with an object instance `{number: Port_role}`, where the value of the `number` property is the interface type `Port_role`.

In the second try you are trying to push an object instance `{5: Port_role.input}` into an array of type `Port_Mapping`. There you get an obvious type missmatch, as the object instance you are pushing has no `number` property (and the type of array you are pushing into (`Port_Mapping`) has no property named "5").

Usage:

```
interface Dict {
  [idx: number]: string
}

const i = 5;
const dict: Dict = { 1: 'abc', [2]: 'def', [i]: 'ghi' };
dict[7] = 'jkl';
dict[i] = 'mno';
delete dict[2]; // removes the index 2: 'def' entry

const listOfDict: Dict[] = [dict, { 1: 'a', [2]: 'b', [i]: 'c'}];
listOfDict.push({ 1: 'a', [2]: 'b', [i]: 'c'});
```

Comment: Does this work when you use a variable? When I try to do something like` var something: number = 5; this.port_mappings.push({something: Port_role.input});` you still get "Argument of type '{ something: Port_role; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Port_Mapping'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'something' does not exist in type 'Port_Mapping'." I don't understand why though something *is* the number 5. Why would 5 work, but something doesn't?

Comment: @GrantCurell when you do `1. var x = 5; 2. var obj = { x: 6 }` the 'x' from 1. and 2. are completely unrelated. In 1. it's a variable, in 2. it is a property name in that object instance. I will update the answer with "usage"

Comment: apologies for just being incredibly dense. From the example shown - that looks like it still requires you to actually use a previous defined number as the key though? What I can't seem to figure out is how to get it to accept { <some_numerical_var>: <value>}. I don't know the key's numerical value ahead of time.

Comment: @GrantCurell just put the variable/value to be used as index into square brackets - `{ [<some_numerical_var>]: <value>}`. 'const' in TS is not a compile-time constant - it can be a run-time resolved value, same as 'var'. It just means "read-only"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TypeScript Record https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt

Comment: It's not clear to me how to use this to accomplish the objective. Something like this? `export const Port_mapping: Record<number, Port> = {};` will compile without error, but obviously it has an empty value that can't be assigned. I tried playing with the syntax, but I couldn't find a way to export the record as a generic type like I do with interface.